# Checking if bits set to 1

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to check whether the last 2 bits in a byte variable have been set to 1. This is what I have:

```
if ((my_byte & (1 << 0)) == 1 && (my_byte & (1 << 1)) == 1)
```

However, if it doesn't seem to be working as the code does not go into the if statement. I am certain the value of my_byte is 3.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about `if (my_byte & 3 == 3)` or `if (my_byte & 0b11 == 0b11)` since Java7?

Comment: Very good, but note operator precedence; see answers.

Answer (score 4):

Use `'if ((my_byte & 0b11) == 0b11)'`

i.e. you're ANDing your number with a number with the two final bits both set to 1. The expression will be true if, and only if, m_byte has its last two bits set to 1.

Comment: `If` needs `boolean` not `int`.

Comment: @Pshemo  This should be faster way because bitwise operator.. am I correct?

Comment: My money is on AND being faster than bitwise shift. i.e. prefer my solution for speed (and clarity).

Comment: It should be `(my_byte & 0b11) == 0b11` not `(my_byte & 0b11) != 0`. For example: in case that `my_byte = 0b10` or `0b01`

Comment: jonchen902: are they not equivalent? And, futhermore I avoid having two 0b11 literals so is more easily extensible to other bit patterns, no?

Comment: @Bathsheba entire `if` condition should be in parenthesis :). Also your test is not perfect. Lets say `my_byte = 0b01`, then `0b01 & 0b11` = `0b01` which is `!= 0` so test will return `true`, but it should be wrong because there are no two ones at the end.

Comment: Thanks for this but when I try it, I get a Syntax Error on "0b11". Do I need to do something before I can use this kind of notation?

Comment: Just cheat and write 3 instead!

Answer (score 2):

The value of the second `or` statement is `2` if the bit is set:

```
if ((my_byte & (1 << 0)) == 1 && (my_byte & (1 << 1)) == 2)
```

As @johnchecn902 suggests, it becomes clearer if you write it as `(my_byte & (1 << 1)) == 0b10`.

There is also no need to divide this into two steps. The whole expression can be simplified to

```
if ((my_byte & 0b11) == 0b11)
```

Comment: Beware of precedence : It should be `((my_byte & 0b11) == 0b11)`